# How to add identity to an existing project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a project. I want to add identification to it. But an error occurs. I will try to describe by example
I create new project without identity.
Create new class "User".

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Create context

```
 public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
}
```

Update database and add 3 items.

Next I want to add identity.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

Update class

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Update context

```
public class UserContext: IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public UserContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
}
```

Next: Add migrationns

```
Error: 
Identity column 'Id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, 
or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, 
and constrained to be nonnullable.
```

I update migration files

```
//AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id");
AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
```

Next: update-database

```
Error: 
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key 
was found for the object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' 
and the index name 'PK_dbo.AspNetUsers'. 
The duplicate key value is ().
```

How to solve a problem?

Comment: `IdentityUser` is [The default implementation of `IdentityUser<TKey>` which uses a string as a primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-1.1). Which means: use `IdentityUser<int>`.

Comment: I want used full function identity with minimum repair. So i want used string Id

Comment: You need to fill Id column with something. I guess you want to use email address or user name.

Comment: ID column fill autoincrimen value 1,2,3

Comment: I want to transfer the functionality from project that has identity to the project without identity. This first step.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution.
When

```
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id");
```

the value changes to NULL.
So migration update

```
//AlterColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "TmpId", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
Sql("UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET TmpId = Id");
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id");
AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
Sql("UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET Id = TmpId");
Sql("UPDATE dbo.AspNetUsers SET UserNAme = TmpId");
DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "TmpId");
```